# What is the easiest way to implement SVD algorithm for my searched results on Solr?

Tags: solr, mahout, svd

I created my own core on http://localhost:8983/solr and added some documents so I could query. But When I query something like"dog", I want those documents that contains "pooch" will be returned too. So I want to implement SVD algorithm to make some improvement on my results. 
Since I am new to the search engine thing. All I know is that I can use Mahout to implement SVD, but it seems a little bit difficult coz I have to install Maven, Hadoop and Mahout. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `SynonymGraphFilterFactory`**

> This filter maps single- or multi-token synonyms, producing a fully correct graph output. This filter is a replacement for the Synonym Filter, which produces incorrect graphs for multi-token synonyms.
>
> If you use this filter during indexing, you must follow it with a Flatten Graph Filter to squash tokens on top of one another like the Synonym Filter.

Create a file i.e `mysynonyms.txt` in the directory `your_collection/conf/` and put the synonyms with `=>` sign

```
pooch,pup,fido => dog
huge,ginormous,humungous => large
```

And Example Schema will be :

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/> <!-- required on index analyzers after graph filters -->
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonyms.txt"/>
</analyzer>
```

Source : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions

Answer (score 1):

The is another way to augment your index with terms not in the content. Synonyms is good as @ashraful says. But there are 2 other problems you will run into:

1. words used but not in the synonym list
2. behavioral search: using other user behavior as a hint to what they are looking for

These require you to augment the index with terms learned from 1) other searches, and 2) user behavior. Mahout's Correlated Cross Occurrence algorithm can help with both. You can set it up to find terms that lead to people reading an item and (if you have something like purchase or other preference data) conversion items that correlate with items in the index. In the second case you would add user conversions to the search query to personalize the results.

A blog about the technique here: http://actionml.com/blog/personalized_search
The page on Mahout docs here: http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html

You should also look at word2vec, which will (given the right training data) find that "dog" and "pooch" are synonyms regardless of the synonym list because it is learned from the data. I'm not sure how you add word2vec to Solr but it is integrated into Fusion, the closed source product of Lucid.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion!  I am totally new to this.  But my tutor ask me to implement SVD. And I just setup maven, hadoop and mahout for 2 days but I failed , met with loads of problems. And I don't know other ways to implement SVD other than mahout , do you know?